# Boot from USB on MacBook 1.1 (early 2007)

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, usb

I’m trying to install Windows 8 from USB on my MacBook 1.1 (early 2007).

I have tried booting using rEFIt (on 10.6):

- Partition my USB key as MBR: the Windows 8 logo fish stays stuck forever.
- Partition my USB key as GPT: same problem.

I didn’t try to boot Linux EFI from USB but I think it would be the same fail.

I’m really wondering if the problem comes from the MacBook firmware or the way I try to load the Windows installer.

How would you proceed on the Apple generation of MacBook?

Comment: Hello, I did install Windows 8 on my late-2010 iMac and also wasn't able to get it going using an USB stick. I ended up using a DVD and that worked fine. Maybe that's an workaround for you? Btw: Are trying to install the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 8?

Comment: What version of Win 8 are you trying the original MacBooks were 32 bit only.

Comment: If you have the opportunity, make a minimal install of OS X and then install Windows through Boot Camp.  This is what Apple supports, so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install Windows 8.1 by

- Created a BOOTCAMP partition using the 10.6 Boot Camp tool (latest version available for 32-bit Macs)
- Creating a Windows 7 USB stick on a PC using http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool
- Install rEFInd http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/
- Start Windows Windows 7 installation
- During disk/partiton select, choose to format the BOOTCAMP partition as NTFS (still, it refused to install)
- Restart Windows installer, second time it would recognise partition as valid
- Install Windows 7
- Update to Windows 8

However, the Apple drivers for MacBook1,1 is pretty outdated unfortunately. Also, I would say that Windows 7 is a more appropriate OS for MacBook1,1.

Answer (score 0):

This MacBook should support booting from USB as referenced here [Starting from an external USB storage device (Intel-based Macs)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1948)

However as noted in the knowledge base article:

> If you use Boot Camp, you may not be able to boot natively into supported versions of Microsoft Windows XP or Windows Vista operating systems installed on external USB hard drive.

This can probably be extrapolated to USB boot media as well.

According to the [Bootcamp 3.0 installation guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Boot_Camp_Install-Setup_10.6.pdf) it seems to hint that a install CD / DVD disk is required:

> Important: You must use a single full-install Windows installation disc. You cannot use an upgrade version of Windows. If you’re installing Windows XP, you must use Service Pack 2 or later. You cannot install an earlier version of Windows XP and then attempt to update it later.

Mac OS versions up to OS X Lion and MS Windows versions up Windows 7 32 bit  are officially supported to boot on this Mac according to 
[EveryMac's MacBook 1,1 notes on supported operation systems](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/stats/macbook_2.0_white.html)

Comment: The reason for XP or Vista not working is apparently because the necessary USB-drivers has not been loaded when switching over to full kernel control.  To my knowledge this has been remedied in 7 & 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook2,1. I wasn't able to boot from USB during Alt/Option boot selection (Maybe because Boot Camp Assistant disabled USB boot?).

What I did was burn [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) to a CD and booted it. In HDD > Boot Management, there is Plop Boot Manager. In Plop, select USB boot.

The Windows USB flash drive must be formatted using MBR partition scheme and without Rufus MBR. The Rufus MBR prompts to press any key to boot, which does not work on the old MacBook.